# Flutter Flavor build appbundle terminal but signing key is incorrect

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, build

I have a project where I use Flavor with Flutter. In this project, I am building for 10 different companies.

I build as flutter build appbundle -t lib/..._main.dart --flavor=... via the terminal, but Google Play says the signing key is not correct.

There is the necessary editing for key.properties files in my signingConfigs settings on build.gradle.

When I perform the same operation via Android Studio as Build>Generate Signed Bundle / APK, I can manually specify the jks file and get the build correctly.

Why is the project not signed correctly in the terminal?

Comment: can you provide sample key.properties you have? Also, are you sure you are using right signing file in key.properties?

Comment: @SujanGainju storePassword= ***
keyPassword= ***
keyAlias= ****
storeFile= local file path When I print as println keystoreProperties, I see that the information is correct.